# Error loading weights from a Hugging Face model

Tags: python, error-handling, model, huggingface-transformers

I'm using transformers and I already have loaded a model and It works fine:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

task='sentiment'
MODEL = "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

# PT
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL) 
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)
```

but If I try to load another task like "emotion" or "hate", I get this error:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

task='emotion'
MODEL = "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

# PT
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)  ## Here I get the error
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)
```

This error:

```
OSError: Can't load weights for 'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-emotion'. Make sure that:

- 'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-emotion' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or 'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-emotion' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.
```

I have checked it and these models actually exists are Hugging Face models, as you can see [here](https://huggingface.co/models?filter=arxiv:2010.12421), so I dont get why is not working.

Edit: I have noticed that the first time I run it, It works with all the tasks (hate, emotion, sentiment) but If I try to run it again, then I get the error.

Comment: I can not reproduce this with 4.5.1. Which transformers version are you using? Can you try to upgrade it in case you are not already using 4.5.1?

Comment: I was using the 3.1.0 version. Now with 4.5.1. I get no problem and the code runs. Thanks @cronoik

Comment: Edit: With the 4.5.1. version I got the error too. The error appears the second time I run the code, never at the beggining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# PT
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL) 
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(MODEL)
```

Add the third line to this section, rename or remove the model folder you had already, and try again. This time it should indeed work more than once. I hope this gets you rolling!

Comment: It works! Can you explain me why? Why I cannot download the tokenizer a second time?

Comment: This isn't something I'm super familiar with myself, but a problem I faced a few times working with some similar models was that if you don't save the config/tokenizer/model (depending on what each used) this way they would all throw a similar error. I'm assuming it's just due to you only having some of what the code wants stored locally when you run it the second time so it panics and gives up.

Comment: solution is also valid for TF version...